# is there a keyring service independent of a desktop?

Tags: server, passwords, key, gnome, kde-plasma

I have a minimal linux server, e.g., minimizing the number of bytes on disk used by executables, shared objects, etc. All of the keyring services I have found require a dekstop environment, Gnome or KDE. Is there such a service which does not require a desktop?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a programming question (though its answer may give you the information needed to make this a programming question).  Maybe try [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), [Unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

How about using [libsecret](https://developer.gnome.org/libsecret/unstable/)?

It seems to at least work with at least the GNOME Keyring and KDE ksecretservice daemons, but more generally with any daemon implementing the [Secret Service API](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/secret-service/).